# Why I am getting "Type reference cannot find type" exception while referring ResourceDictionary in C# code

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I am using following code to Create a Style in Resource Dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:Chart="clr-namespace:TestApp.Controls.Chart">


<Style x:Key="DefaultLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Chart:LabelStyle}">
    <Setter Property="LabelBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="LabelFontSize" Value="12.0"/>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="OrientationAngle" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="LabelPlacement" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="LabelOrientation" Value="Normal"/>
</Style>
```

and then trying to consume it using following code:

```
 public static void LoadSkin()
    {
        var _skinDictionary = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("/Chart;component/Resources/DefaultSkin.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) };
    }
```

but its throwing "Type reference cannot find type" exception, mentioning that unable to find LabelStyle. But LabelStyle is a public class in Chart.

What I am doing wrong here?

I tried checking other threads here with similar problem and tried to make those changes,

still it doesn't works :(

Please let me know your suggestions..!!

Comment: Is the `TestApp.ControlStyles.Chart` namespace in the same assembly as the XAML?

Comment: What kind of class is `LabelStyle`? The name implies that it is also a style, which would be strange. [TargetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx) must specify a type derived from FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement.

Comment: Are you trying to add to the style already defined for some control? If so you need to do something like this: <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">

Comment: TestApp.ControlStyles.Chart is in the same Assembly, in fact its a User Control.

Comment: LabelStyle is a Class which defines Styles for Labels to be added to the Canvas, this class contains all dependency properties. This class is not deriving from FrameworkElement or any Container. In this scenario waht I should do to allow styling my control from a XAML??

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply a Style to a type that is not derived from FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement. See the *Remarks* section in [Style.TargetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype).

Maybe your `LabelStyle` class could simply get its property values from resources like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary ...
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <sys:Double x:Key="LabelFontSize">12.0</sys:Double>
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```